# How to get app signature hash code in native?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, native

Is there any way to get app signature hash in native?

```
Signature[] sigs = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;
for (Signature sig : sigs)
{
    log.i("MyApp", "Signature hashcode : " + sig.hashCode());
}
```

Comment: Yes. Call the same methods from your native code through JNI. If you have a more specific problem, please edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: @Michael how should i call this method?

Comment: Do you know how to use Java classes from C? If not, google for _"jni call java from c"_ and start reading. If you already know how to do that, it's just a matter of getting the necessary `jmethodID`s for the `Application`, `PackageManager`, `PackageInfo` and `Signature` classes and calling them in the same order as in the Java code, possibly with some extra string / byte array conversions along the way.

Comment: @michael The attack vector is that someone can intercept the Java calls and return their own results through hacks on the VM. By performing the signature checks in native code, this attack is mitigated. However, if the native calls simply calls back to Java, then this solution is no more secure than simply performing this check in Java. For that reason, I think amirZ was looking for a _pure native solution_.